# Recursive BASH renaming

Tags: bash

**EDIT:** Ok, I'm sorry, I should have specified that I was on Windows, and using win-bash, which is based on bash 1.14.2, along with the gnuwin32 tools. This means all of the solutions posted unfortunately didn't help out. It doesn't contain many of the advanced features. I have however figured it out finally. It's an ugly script, but it works.

```
#/bin/bash
function readdir
{
  cd "$1"
  for infile in *
  do
    if [ -d "$infile" ]; then
      readdir "$infile"
    else
      renamer "$infile"
    fi
  done
  cd ..
}

function renamer
{
  #replace " - " with a single underscore.
  NEWFILE1=`echo "$1" | sed 's/\s-\s/_/g'`
  #replace spaces with underscores
  NEWFILE2=`echo "$NEWFILE1" | sed 's/\s/_/g'`
  #replace "-" dashes with underscores.
  NEWFILE3=`echo "$NEWFILE2" | sed 's/-/_/g'`
  #remove exclamation points
  NEWFILE4=`echo "$NEWFILE3" | sed 's/!//g'`
  #remove commas
  NEWFILE5=`echo "$NEWFILE4" | sed 's/,//g'`
  #remove single quotes
  NEWFILE6=`echo "$NEWFILE5" | sed "s/'//g"`
  #replace & with _and_
  NEWFILE7=`echo "$NEWFILE6" | sed "s/&/_and_/g"`
  #remove single quotes
  NEWFILE8=`echo "$NEWFILE7" | sed "s/’//g"`

  mv "$1" "$NEWFILE8"
}

for infile in *
do
  if [ -d "$infile" ]; then
    readdir "$infile"
  else
    renamer "$infile"
  fi
done

ls
```

I'm trying to create a bash script to recurse through a directory and rename files, to remove spaces, dashes and other characters. I've gotten the script working fine for what I need, except for the recursive part of it. I'm still new to this, so it's not as efficient as it should be, but it works. Anyone know how to make this recursive?

```
#/bin/bash
for infile in *.*;
do 
#replace " - " with a single underscore.
NEWFILE1=`echo $infile | sed 's/\s-\s/_/g'`; 
#replace spaces with underscores
NEWFILE2=`echo $NEWFILE1 | sed 's/\s/_/g'`; 
#replace "-" dashes with underscores.
NEWFILE3=`echo $NEWFILE2 | sed 's/-/_/g'`; 
#remove exclamation points
NEWFILE4=`echo $NEWFILE3 | sed 's/!//g'`; 
#remove commas
NEWFILE5=`echo $NEWFILE4 | sed 's/,//g'`; 
mv "$infile" "$NEWFILE5";
done;
```

Comment: I think it is more superuser than stackoverflow but if it just to fix something on a particular linux box I would use find and rename.

Comment: If you use `*.*` you won't match files that don't contain the "`.`". In Bash, it's more idiomatic to just use `*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those semicolons are superfluous and there's no reason to use all those variables. If you want to put the `sed` commands on separate lines and intersperse detailed comments you can still do that.

```
#/bin/bash
find . | while read -r file
do
    newfile=$(echo "$file" | sed '
        #replace " - " with a single underscore.
        s/\s-\s/_/g 
        #replace spaces with underscores
        s/\s/_/g
        #replace "-" dashes with underscores.
        s/-/_/g
        #remove exclamation points
        s/!//g
        #remove commas
        s/,//g')
    mv "$infile" "$newfile"
done
```

This is much shorter:

```
#/bin/bash
find . | while read -r file
do
    # replace " - " or space or dash with underscores
    # remove exclamation points and commas
    newfile=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/\s-\s/_/g; s/\s/_/g; s/-/_/g; s/!//g; s/,//g')
    mv "$infile" "$newfile"
done
```

Shorter still:

```
#/bin/bash
find . | while read -r file
do
    # replace " - " or space or dash with underscores
    # remove exclamation points and commas
    newfile=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/\s-\s/_/g; s/[-\s]/_/g; s/[!,]//g')
    mv "$infile" "$newfile"
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me, your solution doesn't work :(
I'm using win-bash with gnuwin32 tools, and I get "option not availible[sic] on this NT BASH release" on the find line. win-bash is based on bash 1.14.2 unfortunately, so it doesn't support newer features. Thanks though.

Comment: I've marked yours as the answer for other people looking to a solution, who are on actual *nix systems. I'm sure it works on them.

Comment: @Ryan: You can probably omit the `-r`. That's just there to handle backslashes without interpreting them as escapes.

Comment: Nope. I'm not sure exactly what it's not supporting, but I suspect it is the piping the output of find. Regardless, I've solved it now, through some ugly scripting :p. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

`find` is the command able to display all elements in a filesystem hierarchy. You can use it to execute a command on every found file or pipe the results to `xargs` which will handle the execution part.

Take care that `for infile in *.*` does not work on files containing whitespaces. Check the `-print0` option of `find`, coupled to the `-0` option of `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

In bash 4, setting the `globstar` option allows recursive globbing.

```
shopt -s globstar
for infile in **
 ...
```

Otherwise, use `find`.

```
while read infile
do
 ...
done < <(find ...)
```

or

```
find ... -exec ...
```

Comment: Ok, looks like I have a lot more to learn still, because you've got me confused right now. I'm actually using bash on Windows, with the gnuwin32 tools and win-bash, which is based on bash 1.14.2 apparently.

Thanks for the help so far, I'll try and see if I can figure it out from here, but if you could finish the script for me to see as an example, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've used 'find' in the past to locate files then had it execute another application.
See ['-exec'](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
rename 's/pattern/replacement/' glob_pattern
```

Comment: e.g. `rename 's/\s+//g' 'File Name With Whitespace'`  will rename it to `FileNameWithWhitespace`